# Не могу получить ID Склада организации при поиске товара из ассортимента

Tags: moysklad-json-api, мойсклад-api

Выполняю подключение по API и встала потребность получить id организации и склада при создании отгрузки товара, но проблема в том, чтобы создать отгрузку, надо сначала указать с какого именно склада это произойдет и id организации, товары предварительно вытаскиваю через Filter и потом по выборке отправляю к себе на сервер для формирования отгрузки, прежде чем отправить ее на создание. Спасибо тем кто откликнется

Мне нужно получить ид Организации и склада одновременно при получении товара из Ассортимента, чтобы потом выполнить отгрузку, но в документации ничего не написано как это сделать, хотя бы ID Склада, любого где есть этот товар?

Пытался так:

```
$url = $this->url."entity/assortment?expand=agent,store,organization";
        if(!is_null($string)){
            $url = $url.'&filter=search='.urlencode($string);
        }
        $url = $url."&order=name,asc;code,asc&imit=20";
```

Но приходит просто список без вложенных данных на основе фильтра и все

Comment: Вопрос не указан

Comment: поправил в чем вопрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем подходящего решения я не нашел как вытащить склад прицепом с какими-то данными, в итоге пришел к выводу получить сначала список доступных складов и организаций, передать тот, с которого и будет происходить списание, организация

Answer (score -1):

При запросе ассортимента склад не выводится. Список полей указан в доке https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

expand не добавляет данные, он расширяет вложенные данные (добавляет информацию о них)

подробнее про expand в той же доке
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-expand

Comment: я видел это, и все же некоторые сущности позволяют вытащить это, хотя в документации об этом могут и умолчать, так как это было описано где-то выше, я и написал, что попробовал через expand, но не вышло (вдруг бы помогло), может кто знает другой способ, не в лоб а скажем через поиск товара внутри склада, но там даже такого способа я не нашел как вытащить, поэтому и вопрос такой

p.s. список полей я видел

Answer (score -1):

В МоемСкладе ассортимент и склады не связаны в том смысле, что любой товар может хранится на любом складе.

Описанная ситуация довольно странная. Вы хотите создать отгрузку с произвольного склада, лишь бы на нем был в наличии этот товар. В реальности же товар отгружается с какого-то конкретного склада.

Если же вы все-таки хотите найти склад, где есть определенный товар, воспользуйтесь [отчетом остатки](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-get), запрашивая его для определенного товара через параметр **product.id**.

---

С организацией же ассортимент вообще не связан. Отгрузка как документ создается для определенной организации. Из Вашей постановки получается, что вы можете использовать просто любую существующую организацию.

Comment: отчасти правильно меня поняли, я лишь хотел получить список складов, организаций, по логике я шлю запрос от имени своей организации и немного  странно, что я не могу получить это хотя бы через какую нибудь сущность, к примеру почему не могу получить информацию о складах, в которых есть этот товар, когда я пытаюсь его получить (вытаскивая полную инфу), поэтому и сформировался такой вопрос, может быть есть то, о чем я еще не прочитал

Answer (score -1):

id организации(точнее ее meta.href) точно нужно знать заранее, и как сказано выше, эта сущность не как не связана с остатками и самими товарами. В этом есть логика. 
Вам нужно определиться, что влияет на изменение организации. 
Обычно 1 организация = какой то один интернет-магазин или одна розничная точка.
Если этого мало, то наверное есть иные причины для разделения мух от котлет. Например: разные отделы интернет-магазина(опт/розница), разные группы покупателей(физики, юрики, юрики с ндс и т.п.), разные кассы в одном магазине(по факту принадлежащие разным юр единицам).

Про склад не совсем понял. Что делать, если в заказе есть товары, требующие отгрузки с разных складов, что если товар есть на нескольких складах одновременно(что определит приоритет)? Узнать на каком складе есть конкретный товар можно только полным перебором отчета Остатки(проблема если у вас несколько тысяч наименований) или остатки по документу.

Скорей всего проблема в попытке обхода использования документа Заказ покупателя. Именно по ним проще всего отслеживать что из заказа есть на конкретном складе в настоящий момент(в том числе через api.Остатки по документу).

Comment: Товар из разных складов в одной отгрузке - очень просто, есть перечень товаров, из которого я формирую отгрузку, а товар 1 есть на складе 1 и товар 2 на складе 2, но и в счете и в отгрузке они идут вместе, но прикол отгрузки в том, что склад для отгрузки товаров я могу указать либо 1, либо 2, вот и разница, на такой вопрос поддержка мне ответила - товары спишутся в минус, если они отсутствуют на складе 1, а по поводу склада и организации - я хотел вытащить их списки прицепом в один запрос к серверу, а не 3 или 4 (уже не вспомню)